# Setuptools Python function path syntax specification

Tags: python, setuptools

Python Setuptools allow you to specify an import path to a particular module or o specific function within a module or class. The [docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) provide a number of useful examples of this type of path:

```
my_package.some_module:main_func
some_module:SomeClass
some.nested.module:SomeClass.some_classmethod
project_a.tools.htmlgen
```

I'm trying to find a PEP or other documentatation of this function-path syntax. Does this format have an official name and specification?

Comment: Nop AFAIK, just a well-known convention.